# GEE: export image collection to google drive

Tags: google-earth-engine, modis

I am completely new to GEE and want to obtain Modis burned area product for the years 2017-2020 as tiff-files. I worked out this code, but when I run the code it says in the console: object.name is not a function and Invalid GeoJSON geometry. As a geometry I created a rectangle of my study area. What am I doing wrong here?

```
var startDate = '2017-01-01';
var endDate = '2020-12-31';
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/006/MCD64A1')
                  .filterDate(startDate, endDate)
                  .filterBounds(geometry);
print(dataset);
var batch = require('users/fitoprincipe/geetools:batch');
batch.Download.ImageCollection.toDrive(dataset, 'Folder', 
                {scale: 10, 
                 region: geometry.getInfo()["coordinates"], 
                 type: 'float'});
```

Answer (score 0):

It's the way you use a geometry (hand drawn) versus what the custom function is expecting. I assume. But this works:

```
var batch = require('users/fitoprincipe/geetools:batch');
batch.Download.ImageCollection.toDrive(dataset, 'Folder', 
                {scale: 10, 
                 region: geometry, 
                 type: 'float'});
```

Although chrome will probably throw you a warning first which you ignore (wait) before the download tasks appear.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I was able to run the task, however it did not finished and I canceled it after one hour...

Comment: One hour already? How big is your geometry? Can take some time to finish large tasks.